# iPhone NSNumberFormatter for less than 1 value

Tags: iphone, nsnumberformatter

I have a floating point value

```
i.e. 0.0467
```

Want have a string 
`05` 
how can get it? Excluding the decimal point (.).

More precisely, if I have a floating point number, I want to divide it to integral and decimal, preferably into two string parts.

Comment: You want to round up the float value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fDecimal = 0.04567;
NSString * strDecimal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", fDecimal];
NSString * strDecimalPart = [strDecimal substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
```

Answer (score 1):

By following this, you will get desired result.

```
    float floatValue = 0.0467;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", floatValue];
    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2) withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);    // Result will be: 05
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I am doing now. A deviant of the method,    [strTotalDecimal substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2);   Excluding leading zero (0) and decimal separator (./,), whatever it can be!

Answer (score 0):

The setting you are looking for is called *fraction digits*:

```
NSNumberFormatter* f = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease;
[f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

Optionally you can use `-[NSNumberFormatter setRoundingMode:]` to specify how rounding should be done.

Comment: Do you think, [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0467] will return 05? I think it will return "0.05". I want the fraction digits without decimal point.

Comment: @dumbhead Yes it will. To get only the fractions I would use the substring methods on `NSString`. Or possibly `[[numberString componentsSeparatedBy:@"."] lastObject]`

Comment: I am a bit concerned with localization of @".", it can be "," in some countries.

Comment: @dumbhead - Yes it can, use `-[NSNumberFormatter decimalSepator]`, or force a locale you like.